# Heat equation derivation

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, delay-differential-equations

I am struggling with a proposition I found in a paper. It is said that if $f$ satisfies :

$$f'(t) = -f(\alpha t), ~0<\alpha<1$$

Then $f$ can be seen as a function of $t$ and $\alpha$ and also satisfies the heat equation :

$$\frac{df}{d\alpha} = \frac{t^2}{2\alpha}\frac{d^2f}{dt^2}.$$

I know that $f$ can be seen as function of both $\alpha$ and $t$ but I can't get the heat equation from there. Any help would be appreciated. Many thanks !

Comment: It looks like $f$ is a single variable function, so the link to the heat equation doesn't make sense. Can I get a link to the paper please?

Comment: Yes https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022247X98960541?ref=pdf_download&fr=RR-2&rr=7cf947f28a080207 , page 4 at the end. $f$ can be seen as a function of both variable since its value on $t$ depends on $\alpha$...

Comment: It sounds like what you are doing is generally along the lines of developing a self-similar solution to the heat equation, but somehow in reverse; that terminology may help you with your search.

Comment: If you read carefully, it says that the power series solution (2) from page 1 satisfies the heat equation.

Comment: Thank you @CheeHan ! but (2) is an analytic solution of (1), isn't it ?

Comment: thank you @Ian, I will search with these terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the paper it is defined in equation (2)

$$y(t,q)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n q^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}}{n!}t^n$$

From which you can easily see that
$$\frac{\partial y}{\partial q}(t,q)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n(n-1)}{2} \frac{(-1)^n q^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}-1}}{n!}t^n=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=2}^\infty n(n-1)~\frac{(-1)^n q^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}-1}}{n!}t^n$$

$$\frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial t^2}(t,q)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty n(n-1)~\frac{(-1)^n q^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}}{n!}t^{n-2}=\sum_{n=2}^\infty n(n-1)~\frac{(-1)^n q^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}}{n!}t^{n-2}$$
From which we get the "heat equation" (It's not actually the heat equation but anyway):
$$2\frac{\partial y}{\partial q}(t,q)=\frac{t^2}{q}\frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial t^2}(t,q)$$